# Does numpy.random.randint() always return a contiguous and aligned ndarray?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, random

Does numpy.random.randint(), when supplied a `size` argument and thus returning an ndarray, always return a *contiguous* and *aligned* array?

(I'd like to be sure the return value's data, reached via PyArray_DATA, can be safely and efficiently indexed by C pointer arithmetic. The [numpy.random.randint() docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html) don't make a clear guarantee.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [current source code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/8206e8df495e0bd050e57cd74f6177058a61dc2b/numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.pyx#L952), raw C-indexing access to the ndarray is exactly how it's filled before being returned:

```
        array = <ndarray>np.empty(size, int)
        length = PyArray_SIZE(array)
        array_data = <long *>PyArray_DATA(array)
        with self.lock, nogil:
            for i from 0 <= i < length:
                rv = lo + <long>rk_interval(diff, self. internal_state)
                array_data[i] = rv
        return array
```

So accessing it the same way should be fine.